# How to Insert Icon on Static Text Control in MFC?

Tags: c++, static, mfc, static-text

I'm trying to use `CStatic::SetIcon()` like this.

```
HICON DSN_ICON = static_cast<HICON>(
      ::LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),
      MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON_MYICON),
      IMAGE_ICON,
      16, 16,
      LR_DEFAULTCOLOR) );

m_staticMyStatic.SetIcon(DSN_ICON);
m_staticMyStatic.SetWindowText( _T("test") );
m_staticMyStatic.EnableWindow(TRUE);

※ P.S : CSatic m_staticMyStatic;    // DDX_Control
```

When I tested using CButton, I made it. But CStatic is failed.
How can I do it?

Comment: What exactly failed?

Comment: Why are you calling `SetWindowText` after `SetIcon`?

Comment: @Victor There is no My Icon on Static text control. Just show Static text "test".

Comment: @PaulSanders I want to show icon with text on Static text Control. So I do it. CButton is success. But I want to do on Static Text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have both text and an image in a static control. The [CStatic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstatic-class) documentation introduces the control with this:

> A static control displays a text string, box, rectangle, icon, cursor, bitmap, **or** enhanced metafile.

The Win32 documentation for the static control lists the available [Static Control Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-static-controls#static-control-types). A static control can be either one of those at any given time.

If you need both text and an image, you can either use 2 separate static controls, or implement an [owner-drawn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-static-controls#owner-drawn-static-control) control.

Comment: So I just add another Static Text Control and insert the Icon on that Static Text Control.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, CStatic needs to have a style SS_ICON.

Comment: How to set style SS_ICON?

Comment: If you use Resource Editor (Visual Studio, Dialog Editor) - in properties of Label you should set "Type" to "Icon".

Comment: If you use CreateWindow (creation from code) you should add SS_ICON to style definition.

Comment: In Resource Editor you should add element of "Picture Control" type. Later this element will be variable with CStatic type.